# Pip installing kerosene gives unicodeDecodeError

Tags: unicode, compiler-errors, pip

I'm trying to execute `pip3 install kerosene` from a nvidia-docker container. I get the error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-16cx_v3e/fuel/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    LONG_DESCRIPTION = f.read().strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1803: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-0e0cswbo/fuel/
```

I googled this error and saw that some people got it from having non-ascii characters in working directory or username, but I don't think this is the case for me. Does anybody know a fix or how I can look into this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/mila-udem/fuel/commit/836691e7ad7c59b402c665329f9babb45e7045eb) in fuel 2 years ago but it's not included in the package at PyPI. Install from Github:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git#egg=fuel
```

Comment: So I didn't actually have fuel installed and was relying on kerosene to install it, but it turns out I get the same error when trying to pip install fuel. The reason I need it is because there's a GitHub project I'm trying to run that uses kerosene for some reason: https://github.com/ChihebTrabelsi/deep_complex_networks

Comment: The bugfix is not included in the package at PyPI. Install from Github. See update in the answer.